# Classes emulating abstract data types?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

According to the Python Tutorial (9.7. Odds and Ends):

> A piece of Python code that expects a particular abstract data type
>   can often be passed a class that emulates the methods of that data
>   type instead. For instance, if you have a function that formats some
>   data from a file object, you can define a class with methods `read()`
>   and `readline()` that get the data from a string buffer instead, and
>   pass it as an argument.

Does this means I should pass a class object as an argument? I know that a class is essentially "a wrapper around the contents of the namespace created by the class definition", but if I already have a function to do this job (format some data from a file object), why do I need to define a class capable of doing it?

Or, in other words, to format some data from a file object, why is defining a class superior to defining a function?

Have I misunderstood this paragraph? And I would appreciate it very much if someone can provide some examples on it.

Comment: I think what  its trying to say is that as long as the object you pass has the methods that the function or class you pass it to actually calls, then it will work. This might be useful for example if you wished to wrap the real class or if you wished to use a mock object that would make your testing easier. When you pass an object the caller can exercise any of the functions or properties that that class provides, with a function all it can really do is call it. So it depends what you need to do.

Comment: I don't think it is implying superiority. I guess in this specific case if a function manipulates an object by calling both methods `read()` and `readline()` you'd be better suited to pass a `class` that defines those instead of passing two functions.